`DataIntegrityViolationException` on clearing a Collection with SpringData / JPA / Hibernate
Case:
I have an entity like this:
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<Foo> foos = Lists.newArrayList();

On clearing the list, ie on running these two lines:
user.getFoos().clear();
userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

I get this stacktrace:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Column 'user_id' cannot be null] [update foo set user_id=null where user_id=?]; SQL [update foo set user_id=null where user_id=?]; constraint [null]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:290) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy205.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]


Fix:
Remove @JoinColumn and use MappedBy attribute, ie replace:
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<Foo> foos = Lists.newArrayList();

with:
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<FlatSetting> flatSettings = Lists.newArrayList();

